# Normals on face

Tags: modeling

How do I see "normals" on face - for example how do I see the dot on the face?

How do I see the vertical line that shows the normal?

Is there a way I can select the face without having to select the dot I can see it in wireframe mode?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question per post. Use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your text (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and delete 
one of the questions. Then ask the second one (and any other questions) 
as a separate post. One question per post is how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: The example actually had less information that the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the normals of the faces, open the *Viewport Overlays* panel, go down to the bottom and enable the option:

[image]

With the *Face Orientation* option you can also quickly see if the faces have the right orientation (blue) or if they are inverted (red):

[image]